# Create a multi IP proxy on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I use GCP to create a multiple IP proxy for Web crawler.

I have created VPC and new instance with multiple nic's.

My config squid is as follows (part of it):

```
    http_port 10000
    http_port 10001
    acl port1 myport 10000
    acl port2 myport 10001
    tcp_outgoing_address 10.170.0.4 port1
    tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.0.2 port2
```

After I restart squid,
I can access proxy on port 10000(nic0, default)
but i cannot access on port 10001(nic1, default)

I can ping my nic1 ip address 10.0.0.2 in console, but cannot ping nic1 external ip.

How do I configure my NIC's to respond to ping on public IP ?

Comment: Can you share more about your VM setup ? Have you checked if [GCP firewall](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/list) is configured to respond to pings (ICMP) from the internet, if not sure create a proper rule and check again. Also keep in mind that a single GCP VM can only have one public IP (despite having multiple NIC's). If you provide more details I can answer your question more precisely.

Comment: First of all thank for your comment. I have create firewall to allow squid port. i create a test on [Connectivity Tests](https://console.cloud.google.com/net-intelligence/connectivity/tests/list) it passed. I have create vpc1 for 10.0.0.0/24 and a public ip, vpc2 for 10.0.2.0/24 and another public ip, mapping nic1 to vpc1, mapping nic2 to vpc2. I can ping nic1,nic2 internal ip, but cannot ping nic1,nic2 public ip. Only nic0(default) public ip can be ping. In your comment, you mean that even I set multiple NIC, each NIC have a public ip, the public ip still cannot use?

Answer (score 2):

You have two ways to be able to use multiple external IP's with one VM.

### 1. Hard way

**This approach (which you tried) is a little more complicated.**

By design if you attach multiple interfaces to a single VM only the first one (NIC0) is configured with the route to the Internet. You have to congigure separate routing table for every additional interface (see [Configuring policy routing](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces#configuring_policy_routing)).

> For Google supported images, when you need a secondary network
> interface (an interface other than nic0) to communicate with any IP
> address not local to the primary subnet range of that secondary
> interface's associated subnet, you need to configure policy routing to
> ensure that egress packets will leave through the correct interface.
> In such cases, you must configure a separate routing table for each
> network interface using policy routing.

Additionally you have to create separate VPC networks for each NIC and if you want to use more than two [you need to have a machine with more CPU's](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces#max-interfaces) (which is another limitation).

> In general, the following rules apply for n1-standard-x, n1-highmem-x,
> n1-highcpu-x, f1-micro, g1-small and custom VMs:
>
> 2 network interfaces for VM <= 2vCPU 1 network interface per vCPU for
> VM > 2vCPUs, with a cap of max 8 network interfaces per VM

Final step is to add proper rules to the GCP Firewall allowing traffic in & out from your VM.

As you see it can be done but has some steps and you still are limited to only 8 NIC's on a single VM.

### 2. Easy way

I'd personally try this approach which is much easier - doesn't specify the VM type (it can be even `micro`).

You can use [Protocol Forwarding Rules](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/protocol-forwarding/).

Steps to fallow (I used `gcloud` utility).

- You need to have one VM (with a single public IP attached). You can use the one that you already have or create a new one if the configuring it from scratch isn't too much work. If you don't create one with `gcloud compute instances create vm2 --tags=tag1`
- Then create a firewall rule that will allow traffic to your VM: `gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow80 --direction=INGRESS --priority=1000 --network=default --action=ALLOW --rules=tcp:80 --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0 --target-tags=tag1`
- [Create target-instance](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/target-instances/create) for your VM: `gcloud compute target-instances create tar1 --instance vm2`
- lastly create forwarding rules itself: `gcloud compute forwarding-rules create forward1 --ip-protocol TCP --ports 80 --target-instance tar1`

*I've used "[network tags](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags)" in this example to simplify the application of any firewall rules and forwarding rules below. Have a look at the documentation if it's not clear to you.*

When you run `gcloud compute forwarding-rules list` you should get

```
$ gcloud compute forwarding-rules list
NAME      REGION        IP_ADDRESS     IP_PROTOCOL  TARGET
forward1  europe-west3  34.107.72.88   ICMP         europe-west3-c/targetInstances/pf-target-instance
forward2  europe-west3  35.246.227.80  ICMP         europe-west3-c/targetInstances/pf-target-instance
forward3  europe-west3  35.198.70.64   ICMP         europe-west3-c/targetInstances/pf-target-instance
```

Each forwarding rule needs it's own unique public IP - when you create one as described a new ephemeral public IP is assigned to it. You can [reserve some static IP's](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) beforehand and then assign them to newly created forwarding rules.

You can find forwarding rules in the console: Network Services > Load Balancing > Advanced > [Forwarding Rules](http://console.cloud.google.com/net-services/loadbalancing/advanced/forwardingRules/list). **In this particular example you cannot use console to create a forwarding rules due to `target-instance` use. Console only allows creating rules to direct it to `target-pool`.**

You have to use `gcloud utility` in this case.

Comment: gcloud compute target-instances create squid-target-instance --instance my-instance-name


Thank you. I tried for these two days still not very understand on soluation 2. Please correct if I am wrong: 
1. create a instance and install squid, set http_port 80 in squid this case and excute TAG="myproxy". 
2. Run firewall rule, change $MY-VM-TAG to $TAG. 
3. Run Create target-instance, squid-target-instance is name of squid, my-instance-name is a new instance name. 
4. Run forwarding rules
But i use proxy by server ip and port 80 in browser, it not work.

Comment: Moreover, I can find new external ip created use by myrule1, Target pool
 is squid-target-instance. But i unable to find it. How can I find this rule in console?

Comment: You can't create target-instance or find it in the console, also you can't create forwarding rules that use it. I've updated my answer to include your questions (also some info about "tagging" instances.

Comment: I follow the step now I can create firewall, target-instances and forwrading. However, it still no work. May I ask more question the verify my config: 1. my-instance-name is the squid VM name? 2. my squid VM need to change config for forwarding-rules? 3. In my browser, I input VM's ip and port 80 to forwarding traffic to squid-target-instance's IP? Wojtek_B You are great! Thank you.

Comment: I've edited my answer so you can literally copy-paste gcloud commands - please remember to add `--zone=ZONE` - otherwise you will be asked each time to select zone.

Comment: I can create rules and vm by your command. Any software need to install or config inside vm2? In my browser, I use vm2ip:80 as a proxy? Because I found some documents need to install Apache in VM, I don't know is it correct on this case. Thanks.

Comment: You have to install Squid (and other software if needed) by yourself. I found many tutorials how to do it on Debian 10 Buster: [here](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/squid-http-proxy-debian-10/) and [here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-and-configure-squid-proxy-on-debian-10/). If you want to use ports other than 80 you have to add them to your GCP firewall rule too. What is your goal here - why do you want to use Squid ? To use your proxy just type into your browser a public IP of one of the forwarding rules you created (you don't have to add :80 at the end).